# What is the time complexity of this code, where one loop grows geometrically and the other decays algebraically?

Tags: big-o

I have a guess,but I am not sure.

This is the problem:

```
for (a = 1 ; a<n ; a= 2*a) do {
     for (b=n; b > 0; b=b-a) do {
     }
}
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow, so I hope the formatting was right.

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is more about describing complexity and scalability, not actual run-time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the complexity. But thanks for noticing and replying.

Comment: Do you mean `b=b-i`, or `b=b-a`? (As of "asked 35 minutes ago")

Comment: b = b-a , Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a useful maxim for reasoning about big-O notation that goes like this:

> When in doubt, work inside out!

More specifically, if you're trying to figure out the complexity of a loop nest, start with the innermost loop and keep replacing it with a simpler statement summarizing the amount of work done.

In your case, you have these loop:

```
for (a = 1 ; a<n ; a= 2*a) do {
     for (b=n; b > 0; b=b-a) do {

     }
}
```

Let's begin with the inner loop:

```
for (b=n; b > 0; b=b-a) do {

}
```

How many times will this loop run? Well, we begin with `b` equal to `n`, and on each iteration `b` decreases by `a`. That means that the number of iterations of this loop is roughly `n` / `a`, so the complexity of this loop is Θ(n / a). We can therefore replace the inner loop with something to the effect of "do Θ(n / a) work" to get this simpler structure:

```
for (a = 1 ; a<n ; a= 2*a) do {
     do Θ(n / a) work;
}
```

Now, let's think about how much work this loop does. Since the amount of work done inside the loop depends on the value of `a`, we're not going to multiply the number of iterations by the work done per iteration, since the work done per iteration isn't a constant. Instead, we'll add up how much work is done on each iteration of the loop.

Notice that the value of a increases as 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ..., until we overshoot n. Plugging those values into the work done inside the loop gives a runtime of

> Θ(n / 1 + n / 2 + n / 4 + n / 8 + n / 16 + ... )
>
> = n Θ(1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ...)

You might recognize that the sum 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... happens to converge to 2. (Do you see why?) As a result, we have that the runtime of this code is

> n Θ(2)
>
> = Θ(n).

So the overall work done here is **Θ(n)**.

The main techniques we used to determine this were the following:

- Work from the inside out, replacing each loop with a summary of how much work it does.
- If a loop counter increases by k on each iteration and stops at n, the loop runs for a total of Θ(n / k) iterations. (This applies equally well if we run it backwards and start at n, decreasing by k.)
- The sum of the geometric series 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ... out to infinity is 2.
- If the work done by a loop is constant per iteration, just multiply the work per iteration by the number of iterations. If the work done per iteration isn't, it's often easier to sum up the work across all loop iterations and then try to simplify the sum.

Hope this helps!